# Room cannot migrate database

Tags: android, android-room

My Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
val userID:String,
val userName:String,
val userRoleName:String,
val adminID:String,
val name:String,
val email:String,
val phoneNumber:String,
val adminType:String,
val batchID:String,
val centerID:String,
val batchName:String,
val centerName:String,
val password:String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

I added the password column;

The migration that I provided is

```
private val migration: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE user_table ADD COLUMN password TEXT")
            }
        }
```

I have used it here

```
private fun buildDB(c: Context): MDatabase {
            val dbName = "lms_database.db"
            return Room.databaseBuilder(c.applicationContext, MDatabase::class.java, dbName)
                .addMigrations(migration)
                .build()
        }
```

I am getting a lengthy error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: user_table(app.database.entities.User).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='user_table', columns={batchName=Column{name='batchName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, centerID=Column{name='centerID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, adminType=Column{name='adminType', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, userName=Column{name='userName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, batchID=Column{name='batchID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, userID=Column{name='userID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, password=Column{name='password', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, phoneNumber=Column{name='phoneNumber', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, adminID=Column{name='adminID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, email=Column{name='email', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, userRoleName=Column{name='userRoleName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, centerName=Column{name='centerName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='user_table', columns={batchName=Column{name='batchName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, centerID=Column{name='centerID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, adminType=Column{name='adminType', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, userName=Column{name='userName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, batchID=Column{name='batchID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, userID=Column{name='userID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, password=Column{name='password', type='Text', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, phoneNumber=Column{name='phoneNumber', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, adminID=Column{name='adminID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, email=Column{name='email', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, userRoleName=Column{name='userRoleName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, centerName=Column{name='centerName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:124)
```

The database already has some data right now.

Comment: you have to use RoomDatabase Datatype When you migrate 
Change `String` to `TEXT`
like 
`database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE user_table  ADD COLUMN password TEXT")`

Comment: I had done it already

Comment: there is some data in the database will I lose it???

Comment: no data will not be lost.

Comment: im still getting the error man

Comment: what am I missing

Comment: I think you are missing nullable constraint: found notNull=false, expected notNull=true (on your password column)

Comment: @ror what should I change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set password `nullable` in entity model or provide non null value during migration. Try setting

**Either**

```
val password:String?
```

**Or**

```
ALTER TABLE user_table ADD COLUMN password TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

**N.B:** Replace empty with your default one

Comment: wow that really worked, how do I provide a non null value during migration??

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLE user_table ADD COLUMN password TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`

Comment: Empty is bad. Assuming your password is hashed, you may want to set hash of some default password.

Comment: hey guys when I add a new entity do I need to write the create query in the migration that I provide??

Comment: could you give an example assuming I am adding the `User` entity from above using  the `userID`, `userName` and the `primary key`. I cannot make it work I'm mostly confused about the primary key

Comment: just the first two columns and the primary key for simplicity

Comment: This is another question. Please ask it in another thread to keep it simple.

Comment: hey @Md.Asaduzzaman I did it....Room needs statements to be written in migrations that do not show errors in runtime it kind of does not do what its said it does. is there a way to generate sqlite statements using the entity classes?? or something similar